# How to update and display Map objects?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

If I have a basic Map object that's being updated/refreshed periodically, how do I display the Map's contents within my view/handlebars?

Any sample code would be great, as I'm still wrapping my head around Ember.

Comment: "Any sample code would be great" - that is valid for your question too. Can you post some code you've already got? Especially your `Map` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Ember.Map` object that comes with Ember is meant for high-performance, mostly internal use, so it doesn't implement Observable, Ember.Array or Ember.Enumerable (requirements for displaying an auto-updating object).

It would be pretty straight-forward to implement a `Map` that supported auto-updating. Can you explain your use-case a bit?